# placing 64 buttons randomly in a girdlaout java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, grid-layout

The goal is to create a create a game like rubrics cube where the user has to rearrange the buttons according to the matched color. This is what I did to place the buttons randomly, but it doesn't work when the buttons are presented. The random order is taken as the ordered order if that makes sense. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
  while(list1.size()!=501){

     int x=rand.nextInt(8);
     list1.add(x);
  }
  while(list2.size()!=501){

     int x=rand.nextInt(8);
     list2.add(x);
  }
  for(int b=0;b<500;b++){
     int l= list1.get(b);
     //System.out.println(l);
     int j= list2.get(b);
     panel.add(buttons[l][j]);
     //System.out.println(buttons[l][j].getBackground());

  }
```

Comment: @Fabian thanks for the edit

Comment: I know this is totally inefficient I tried the efficient way and the Jframe didnt have all 64 buttons

Comment: Please explain your goals, your problem and your code in greater detail. Also consider creating and posting a valid [mcve] program in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

1. Giving the buttons a value of some sort that represents their true order. There are several ways to do this, including putting them in an array of specified order, or extending JButton and giving your class an int value field, or using a HashMap
2. Place these buttons into an `ArrayList<JButton>`
3. Shuffling the ArrayList via `Collections.shuffle(...)`
4. Then adding the buttons to your GUI
5. Alternatively, you could use non-shuffled JButtons and instead shuffle AbstractActions which you then set into the buttons.

The details of any solution will depend on the details of your current program, something that we don't yet know enough about. If you need more detailed help, do consider creating and posting a valid [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

For example, compile and run this, and then read the comments:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RandomButtons extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int ROWS = 8;
    private JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[ROWS][ROWS];
    private List<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<>();
    private JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, ROWS));


    public RandomButtons() {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
                // create new JBUtton
                final JButton button = new JButton("Button");
                // put into array
                buttons[i][j] = button;
                // put into ArrayList
                buttonList.add(button);

                // unique value 0 to 63 for each button
                // order it has been created
                final int value = i * ROWS + j;

                // create one of 64 different color hues using value above
                float hue = ((float) value) / (ROWS * ROWS);
                float sat = 0.7f; // reduce sat so we can see text
                float brightness = 1.0f;
                Color color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, sat, brightness);
                button.setBackground(color); // set button's color
                button.addActionListener(e -> {
                    // display the button's order
                    System.out.println("Value: " + value);
                });

            }
        }
        randomizeButtons();

        JButton randomizeButton = new JButton("Randomize");
        randomizeButton.addActionListener(e -> { randomizeButtons(); });
        JButton orderButton = new JButton("Put in Order");
        orderButton.addActionListener(e -> { orderButtons(); });

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        bottomPanel.add(randomizeButton);
        bottomPanel.add(orderButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void randomizeButtons() {
        buttonsPanel.removeAll(); // remove all buttons
        Collections.shuffle(buttonList); // shuffle the ArrayList

        // re-add the buttons **using the ArrayList**
        for (JButton jButton : buttonList) {
            buttonsPanel.add(jButton);
        }

        // tell JPanel to layout its newly added components
        buttonsPanel.revalidate();
        // and then paint them
        buttonsPanel.repaint();
    }

    public void orderButtons() {
        buttonsPanel.removeAll();  // remove all buttons

        // re-add the buttons **using the 2D array**
        for (JButton[] buttonRow : buttons) {
            for (JButton jButton : buttonRow) {
                buttonsPanel.add(jButton);
            }
        }
        buttonsPanel.revalidate();
        buttonsPanel.repaint();
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        RandomButtons mainPanel = new RandomButtons();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RandomButtons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is with ArrayList is that I have to use 2d ArrayList and I am not sure that is even a thing

Comment: JButton [][] buttons = new JButton[8][8] this is what i am doing

Comment: i am not sure if i can even change that to an arraylist

Comment: @CovertError: you can use an `ArrayList<ArrayList<JButton>>` if need be, but most often you really don't need to do this, and using a single-dimensional array list would likely work fine.

Comment: @CovertError: I'm not saying to change that your 2D array. Understand that you can use *both* a 2D array as you're using **and** an ArrayList. Both can hold the same JButtons. Again, please improve your question and your posted code.

Comment: Thanks soo much you just gave me an idea of how to fix my problem.

Comment: thanks soo much I get what you mean now thanks soo much.